# onChange callback and hooks order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a custom hook to use in a textarea.

I know that setting up 'maxLength' will do the trick in the first place, but unfortunately there is an issue with languages like Korean which combines multiple letters to create a new one.
(Sadly, there is a bug with maximum length in Korean which you can type 1 letter more than the given value)

well, I found a workaround, it works perfectly fine, but I don't exactly understand how the ordering goes. It'll be a great help if someone can help me out.

I have narrowed the code down to the bare minimum of my concern.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export default function useCustomHook() {
    const [notifier, setNotifier] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('third');
    }, [notifier]);

    const changeInput = useCallback(({ target }) => { setNotifier((prev) => !prev); }, []);

    return changeInput;
}
```

so my scenario goes like this.

if you type something, it will trigger the condition, changing the notifier value by triggering setNotifier((prev) => !prev).

After the event, useEffect is called, thus triggering the console.log.

the main point to this question is if this is the right order.

**event triggered
 - setNotifier called
 - event finished
 - rerender
 - useEffect called because notifier had been finished - console.log called**

Thanks in advance

Comment: there are bits of code missing to help understand your question better: where does `notifier` and `setNotifier` come from in your hook file?

Comment: @y_nk sorry about the mistyped code. I've fixed my code.

Comment: You are correct, that is the correct order. state change causes a re render and effect is run after a render.

Comment: @HMR ok, so does that mean even if setState was invoked, it was still in 'wait' mode until changeInput was finally finished?

Comment: Assuming your event handler changeInput does not do any asynchronous stuff then the state will be set after the handler finishes (if it's used as onClick or onChange and such). So if you set multiple states in a handler there will be no re render until the handler is done. If you are having trouble getting the state after you set it them maybe you are accessing a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/), the code posted does not show that but your questions indicate that your actual code may have that problem.

Comment: @HMR omg thank you so much for the answer. I feel perfectly clear now. 'Assuming your event handler changeInput does not do any asynchronous stuff then the state will be set after the handler finishes' this statement is the absolute answer I've been looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @HMR if you don't mind, you may want to use an "answer" so that later OP can mark its question as resolved. All so other people coming to this page can have a clear understanding of the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: @y_nk yep that'd be great. HMR, could you make your comment an answer? That'd be really nice